# All sysv services come back with exit code 1 (service <name> start / status / stop)

Tags: service, sysv

On an amzn linux server, after a cycle of install - cleanup - reinstall exercises, suddenly the system V `service` command didn't work any more (such as: `service docker start`; `service sendmail status`, `service cron stop`). It immediately exited with exit code 1, not executing anything, also not logging anything.
Running `/etc/init.d/docker start` and the like worked.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh` script was missing. I had cleaned up too rigorously at some point (I meant to remove another script).

In the script `/sbin/service`, they source `/etc/init.d/functions`, which in turn sources `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh`, which was missing - exit 1, and silence.